# find exec mv finds an inode (dir), changes dir's name, but returns "No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, find, rename, stderr

The following `find-exec(mv)` command finds a directory named say `prog-3.6.9-stable-gnu` and changes its name sucessfully. Yet, the command also returns:

> find: './prog': No such file or directory

This is the command:

```
find ./ -type d -name 'prog-*' -exec mv {} prog \;
```

I get a similar result when `find-exec(rm)` that dir:

Given the find command comes **before** the working exec unzip (or exec rm -rf for that matter) I want to ask why would I have this stderr? I mean, if the file was found and was changed, why would the stderr be "No such file or directory" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error appears because you are moving a folder "`prog-*`".
The actual behaviour of `find` is:

> **`find`** analyzes first the directory itself, and then its contents.

So, `find`, in your example:
 1. *finds* the directory `prog-3.6.9-stable-gnu`
 2. *renames* it in `prog` (so now has a new name)
 3. tries to access `prog-3.6.9-stable-gnu`
 4. it gives back an error because now, it is not able to find the folder `prog-3.6.9-stable-gnu`

**find**'s order of analysing first the directory, and then its contents, is known as "breadth-first traversal". The opposite is "depth-first traversal". There is an option `-depth` which invokes this. It is interesting to read mentions of `-depth` in the [man page for **find**(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

- "`-depth`: Process each directory's contents before the directory itself."
- "The `-delete` action also implies `-depth`."
- "Don't forget that the find command line is evaluated as an expression, so putting `-delete` first will make find try to delete everything below the starting points you specified."
- "When testing a find command line that you later intend to use with `-delete`, you should explicitly specify `-depth` in order to avoid later surprises."
- "Because `-delete` implies `-depth`, you cannot usefully use `-prune` and `-delete` together."